# What is BRNotificationServerAvailabilityChanges used for on macOS?

Tags: macos

I'm getting the following system.log error in my Mac app:

`notify name "user.uid.501.BRNotificationServerAvailabilityChanges" has been registered 20 times - this may be a leak`

But I'm not sure what's causing it. I can't seem to much info on `BRNotificationServerAvailabilityChanges`. Does anyone know what that notification name is used for?

Comment: This symbol (as well as many others with the `BR` prefix) is defined in the private `CloudDocs.framework` (`strings /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/CloudDocs | grep '^BRNot'`)

Comment: Thanks! I tracked down the log to when an NSOpenPanel is shown for my NSDocument based app. I guess this means it's out of my control and hopefully harmless.